# Revesing matrix columns order in basic way in python

Tags: python, matrix

I would like to invert the order of each matrix column as follows:

```
A = [[ 4,  8, 12, 16],
     [ 3,  7, 11, 15],
     [ 2,  6, 10, 14],
     [ 1,  5,  9, 13]]
```

The required result:

```
A = [[ 1,  5,  9, 13],
     [ 2,  6, 10, 14],
     [ 3,  7, 11, 15],
     [ 4,  8, 12, 16]]
```

As can be seen each column changed its order.

I use the following code for it:

```
B = [row[:] for row in A]

k = 0
for i in range(len(A), -1, -1):
    k = k + 1,
    for j in (range(len(A))):
        B[k, j] = A[i, j]

print(B)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-72c0a8d534ec> in <module>()
      9     k = k + 1,
     10     for j in range(len(A)):
---> 11         B[k, j] = A[i, j]
     12 
     13 print(B)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is a nested list, not a numpy array. To flip it vertically, reverse the outer list:

```
A = A[::-1]
```

To make a full copy:

```
B = [list(row) for row in A[::-1]]
```

You can replace `list(row)` with `row[:]` or `row.copy()`.

If you just want to do proper 2D indexing, you need to pass a separate index to each object in the nested structure:

```
B[k][j] = A[i][j]
```

The index `[k, j]` is really `[(k, j)]`. Numpy arrays can accept a tuple in their index, but list objects can not, as the error tells you. Instead, you need to access each sub-list separately. `B[k]` is a reference to a nested list, so you can assign an element to it with `B[k][j] = ...`.

You may also want to be careful with how you construct your outer loop. The expression `range(len(A), -1, -1)` starts with `len(A)`, which is out of bounds in your list (by definition). You probably want to use `range(len(A) - 1, -1, -1)`.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to edit my basic detailed solution.

Comment: Physicistm, Thanks! But even after editing my code to B[k][j] = A[i][j], I still get an error.

Comment: @Avi. What error? If it's a different error, you might want to ask a different question...

Comment: @Avi. Please don't update your question like that. You've completely invalidated my answer. If you're getting another error now, ask another question. The basic philosophy here is that SO is not a discussion forum. It's a Q&A site that is intended to help future readers. Completely changing your question after it's been answered largely defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Avi. I've updated my answer to address your indexing issue

Comment: @Avi. I really appreciate your attitude of trying to understand your own code rather than accepting canned solutions. When you are ready for it, take a look at the numpy.